# what is a general approach that can be taken for proving $\textrm{lim}_{y \downarrow x}f(y) = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the general approach that can be used to prove that $\textrm{lim}_{y \downarrow x}f(y) = f(x)$?

What I can think of is:

If $f(x) = \textrm{lim}_{c \downarrow 0}f(x+\epsilon),  \textrm{where} \ 0<\epsilon<c,  \ c \in \mathbb{R}$

then substituting $y=x+\epsilon$ should give
$f(x) = \textrm{lim}_{y \downarrow x}f(y)$,

but I am not sure if what I am thinking is correct.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the bad symbol handling from my side, trying to learn how to write symbols at this page. But I hope the point is still clear.

Theorem to prove:

$$ \lim _ { y \downarrow x } f ( y ) = f ( x ) $$

Your way of creating the proof.

$ f ( x ) = \lim _ { c \downarrow 0 } f ( x + \epsilon ) $, where $ 0 < \epsilon < c $, $ c \in \mathbb R$, then substituting $ y = x + \epsilon $ should give $ f ( x ) = \lim _ { y \downarrow x } f ( y )$.

**My Experience:**

If you get the correct result, you have the right approach.
There can sometimes be trouble expressing the solution so everybody directly understands it, and it is very common.

To me your symbols mean:

"$ f ( x ) = $": a function of a variable $ x $ is equal to

"$ \lim _ { c \downarrow 0 } $": the limit as $ c $ goes to $ 0 $

"$ f ( x + \epsilon ) $": of the same function of $ x $ plus $ \epsilon $

"$ 0 < \epsilon < c $": where $ 0 $ is less than $ \epsilon $, and $ \epsilon $ is less than $ c $

"$ c \in \mathbb R $": $ c $ is a real number

"$ y = x + \epsilon $": you add the values from $ x $ and $ \epsilon $ and put the sum in $ y $.

**EDIT:** $ \lim _ { y \downarrow x } f ( y ) = f ( x ) $ so this sounds reasonable.

So I consider your way of proofing it a good way of thinking, and a good way to show what you are thinking. Again this is just **MY** translation from **YOUR** mathematical symbols to English.

Comment: actually $c\downarrow0$ means that $c$ is approaching $0$ from the positive side (so  $c$ is progressively decreasing to 0 from the positive side). it's different than stating $c \rightarrow 0$)... is my approach still correct?

Comment: Okey, I think you only call a limit a limit if it is the same value from both directions(below and above the point). So you need to try from small negative values up to zero, as well as from small positive values down to zero. In other case you call it something like 'limit from positive side', or 'limit from negative side'